# dynatree nodes greater than 3000 performance issue

Tags: jquery, dynatree

We have a use case where we are loading dynatree with more than 3000 nodes. It loads fine, on postinit an ajax is triggered and on callback we are updating the nodes(changing color or icon based on flags got after the ajax call). The performance is pretty slow say for 3000 nodes rendering takes approx. 1 minute or two and the browser hangs occasionally.

For updating each node we use    **node.render()**
My question is should I use any other API to update the node?

Thanks,
Charan

PS:I'm a newbie here so if I have not followed any rules. Please do apologize.

Answer (score 0):

It should be much more performant to set extra classes on the nodes (for example by passing 'addClass' with json) and the add some extra CSS to change the appearance.
Example here: http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-theming.html

**Update**

Do you initialize the tree from HTML or Ajax? Init from Ajax would allow to add the status-dependant classes directly in the JSON response, which would avoid a second Ajax call and all of the extra rendering.

If you really want to go with the posprocess approach, try one `tree.redraw()` instead of separate `node.render()` calls.

Comment: Currently I'm using node.data.addClass = "myClass"; and node.data.icon = "myIcon" based on the status of each node. I'm updating multiple nodes one by one in loop and using node.render() is there any other way to handle this. I really appreciate the support !

Comment: Im initializing the tree using AJAX. I have no issues with that. My scenario is once the tree is initialized i make an AJAX call in an interval of 5 seconds and the callback will update few of the nodes(changing its color and icon based on the status i receive from the AJAX call). So, I use node.render() for the nodes that have to be updated. The browser hangs while doing this and the browser throws "Unresponsive script" which points to jquery.dynatree.js. Hope I'm clear now.